# Is there a way to conditionally block a referer in Google Tag Manager?

Tags: facebook, session, google-tag-manager, http-referer

We have an issue with GA where conversion sources are being lost after a user clicks on a link to our site, goes to the site, and then logs in using Facebook.

My understanding from [GTM tips - implement referral exclusions](https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/implement-referral-exclusions-via-gtm/) is that our site sees the `document.referrer` as coming from Facebook and starts a new session, losing the original referrer. If we know the landing page on our site the user sees after logging into Facebook, is it possible to add code to exclude the FB referrer only for that page? I.e, on that one page we have something like (from the linked article):

```
function() {
  var referrals = [
    'facebook.com'
  ];
  var hname = new RegExp('https?://([^/:]+)').exec({{Referrer}});
  if (hname) { 
    for (var i = referrals.length; i--;) {
      if (new RegExp(referrals[i] + '$').test(hname[1])) {
        return null;
      }
   }
  }
  return {{Referrer}};
}
```

We can't simply add `facebook.com` to the GA exclusion list, as we have campaigns running on Facebook as well, so we'd still need visibility to organic traffic coming from Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy GA tag and modify the copy with this code. Then fire that copy only on pages where you need to block referrer and block original GA tag on same pages.

If you don't want to have multiple GA pageview  tags then use Lookup Table variable based on page paths. For some pages this variable should return your code as a Custom JavaScript variable and a default value should be {{Referrer}}.